# Pulling data from 3rd party to Salesforce

Tags: integration

Requirement - To fetch data in 5 objects in Salesforce from a DB through CSV approach. Data will be stored in remote folder/ http.

Data size - 2000 records per table.

What would be the possible approaches for doing that ?
1.Batch job?
2.Cron job
3.Manual

Any other considerations which needs to be made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a cron job to call the Salesforce Data Loader from the command line and load the data from the files. Each object will require a separate job as the Data Loader only supports a single object being loaded at a time, this also means that the sequence of the jobs needs to take into account any dependencies in the data between the objects.

The data that you want to load would need to be stored in a folder that is accessible by the user that is used to run the Salesforce data loader.

[Data Loader command line interface](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=using_the_command_line_interface.htm)

[Data Loader guide](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/20/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_data_loader.pdf)

It is good practice to have a separate user account used for this with just the permissions needed for the objects in integration not a System Administrator account as that would be able to modify user permissions.

Alternatively Data Loader can be used manually by a user with permissions on the objects (if this includes custom objects then they are likely to need Modify All Data and API permissions)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the folder where the data needs to be stored intermediately?

Comment: It would only need to be a standard folder in the file system that you are using that the user running the Data Loader has read permissions on.

Comment: @David - You mean Notes & Attachment in Salesforce?

Comment: No I meant where the data was held before loading to Salesforce. Can you just clarify is the data going out from Salesforce or coming in from the external database?

Comment: @Data will be placed in a server instance of AWS . Will mentioning the url as data source suffice ? or do I need to put extra validations? regarding LOGIN

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be possible via Data Loader with Bulk Data Load Job.

Comment: I assume you are saying writing a GET/POST jobs and run Dataloader from Command line? Where will the intermediate data be stored?